# The end-of -input character doesn't work

Tags: c++

before I was doing a very simple programming exercise and I have a problem with the end-of-input character. I wrote this program to check if two words repetead in the text :

```
string previous = "";   //initalized to "not a word"
string current;     //current word 
while (cin >> current) {    //input operation 
if (previous == current)    // check if the word is the same as last 
cout << "repetead words : " << current << '\n';
previous = current;
}

cout << previous << "\n" << current << "\n";
```

My book says that if I want to terminate the input operation and to fall out the while loop I must insert the end-of-input character, but, if I insert that character on the same line of my input words I will not fall out the loop.Just if I insert it on a newline it works.Why ? I must insert the end-of-input character on a newline to make it work ?

Comment: No matter if you're using a Linux terminal or a Windows command window, that's how it works, and there's not much you can do about it if you want your program to be portable and only use standard C++.

Answer (score -1):

`std::cin::operator>>` will return [false](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) instead of another reference to `std::cin` when it reaches end-of-stream.  Passing a single *eof* is a way to signal end-of-stream.

When `std::cin` parses only an *eof*, it interprets it specially instead of considering it more data in the stream.  If it parses any data in combination with *eof*, it's just considered data in the stream.

Comment: `std::cin::operator>>` *always* returns a reference to the stream. If the stream reached the end-of-file and failed to read data, because of that, the stream's implicitly-invoked boolean operator will return false. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the stream parsing *only* eof.

Comment: @0x499602D2 As I understand it, the *eof* bit isn't set on the state when there's any additional data passed in the stream.  So, for example if it read 'x y x *eof*', the *eof* bit wouldn't be set.  Although, if it reads '*eof*', the *eof* bit is set on the state (signaling the end-of-stream).

Comment: The eof bit *is* set. But it's only until a read fails does the loop stop. That's because the boolean operator only checks `!fail()`.

Comment: It looks like you're correct if I've read the docs accurately.  The boolean value depends on fail bit (and/or bad bit), which may or may not depend on the eof bit.